# How to fix this error 'Indexing cannot yield multiple results'

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

Using **PCA** I reconstruct an image, now want to calculate the `PSNR` for this image so I used the built in function of `matlab 2014a`:

`data_gray` is a gray image (512x512 double) and the `reconstructData` is the reconstructed Image (512x512 double)
By using this:

```
 [peaksnr, snr] = psnr(data_gray, reconstructData);
```

I got this error **Indexing cannot yield multiple results**.

Comment: Having a variable called `psnr`??

Comment: @NKN psnr() is builtin function in `matlab 2014a`, i didn't used any other `psnr` variable

Comment: @Atif it is, but if you have a also a variable called `pnsr` then that error would pop out in Matlab.

Comment: @AnderBiguri no i dont have any other variable `psnr` in the same code.

Comment: @Atif That's quite weird. Are you sure your workspace does not have that variable? do `clear` and then run your code again.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you Sir, now i got it i've to clear the workspace first, thank you for your help.

Comment: `who` will list the content of your workspace. Next time you are absolutely certain you do not have that variable in the workspace run `who` or `who(variable_name)`.